# Weird behaviour of $(data).filter("…") after $.post

Tags: jquery

I don't use to bother the internet for such trivial matters but this is puzzling: the `filter()` function either returns an HTML object or undefined according to the selector I use, and even some obviously foolproof selectors may return undefined.

An example will be much clearer : http://www.whisno.be/marice/contact.php

Just hit the button and you'll get feedbacks :

```
alert(data);
alert($(data).filter($("#debug").val()).html());
```

I tried several selectors and it just got me confused. Anyone understand what's going on ?

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? Also, it would be much easier to debug if you used `console.log()` instead of alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` instead of `filter`:

```
alert($(data).find(debugValue).html());
```

Output:

> Les délices de Marice

This is the value you get from parsing `data` with jQuery:

[image]

As you can see it doesn't contain the `h1` directly but it does contain the `container` div. `filter` removes all elements that don't match the selector - in this case none match. `find` returns all `h1` elements it can find inside the supplied element list.